# How did the output come out as '10'?

Tags: c, pointers

Given below is the code. Can someone explain the logic behind it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int *i,*j;
    i=(int *)60;
    j=(int *)20;
    printf("%d",i-j);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: `i - j` is pointer difference, size of int in your system is 4 bytes, value-wsie diffidence is `40` that is `10` * `sizeof(int)` , 10 location far to each other.

Comment: Why you people are upvoting this?

Comment: Also, the program invokes undefined behavior if `60` and `20` are not valid addresses.

Comment: You should use `%td` instead of `%d`, `%td` is the format specifier for the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @H2CO3 Does it invoke undefined behavior, when the punned-pointers are never dereferenced? Or was the code changed at some point...? I guess, maybe it does, given the "pointer arithmetic between pointers in unrelated arrays is undefined" case, but I think in this particular case "undefined" will still do something "reasonable"...

Comment: Yes, even if you never dereference the pointers, that's still Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @twalberg "Does it invoke undefined behavior, when the punned-pointers are never dereferenced?" - yes, as I stated, "if 60 and 20 are not valid addresses". Pointer arithmetic on invalid pointers invokes UB. - "but I think in this particular case "undefined" will still do something "reasonable"." - maybe it will. I would also kind of expect it to print something logically predictable on some systems, but complete garbage or crashes on others.

Answer (score 9):

You're assigning the pointers values of 60 and 20.

Since `int*` (pointers), on your platform are 4 bytes each (32bit), and there is a difference of 40 bytes between j and i, `i-j` returns `40 / sizeof(int)`, which prints `10`.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the pointer arithmetic.
When you add some value to a pointer, the result will depend of the type of the pointer. On your system, `sizeof(int)` seems to be equal to 4 bytes, so when you do :

```
int    *p = 0x1000; //totally dumb value, just for example
printf("%p\n", p + 1);
```

This will print 0x1004.

So : (int*)60 - (int*)20 = 10, because 10 * 4 (the size of `int` on your system).

Comment: @ReedCopsey No, that is incorrect. The base type of the pointer is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

Distance between two pointers of type `T` is calculated nearly as `(a - b) / sizeof (T)`. If you say

```
int* a = 0xdeadbeef;
int* b = a + 1;
```

then numeric distance between a and b will be sizeof(int) (generally 4) but not 1. And in case

```
char* x = 0x12345678;
char* y = x + 1;
```

distance will be exactly 1.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on `void *` is not standard C, it's not permitted. Probably you meant `char *`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yep, bad me, forgot it. Sorry, it is now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i and j are pointers to `int`s. On a 4 byte machine, `int`s are 4 bytes long, and the difference between the pointer 2 to consecutive `int`s will be 4. `60 - 20 / 4` is - err - 10

Comment: `60 - 20 / 4` is 55. What you probably meant is `(60 - 20) / 4`.

Comment: *On a 4 byte machine, ints are 4 bytes long* -> it's not true on every 32bits system.

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess you got an answer but here is the title; you have to consider the size of the 
variable, which means, in this case that sizeof(int)==4. so 40 bytes equal to 10 int's(in your operation system).

Answer (score -1):

```
60-20 => 40 bytes.
sizeof(int *) = 4 bytes.
i => int *; j=int*
```

So, when you do 60-20, you are doing (int * - int *) i.e. how many int * are in 60-20?

```
60-20 = 40 
40/4 => 10.
```

NOTE: assumption is that sizeof(int *) is 4 bytes.

Comment: "i.e. how many int * are in 60-20?" - no, it counts how many `int`s there are. "assumption is that sizeof(int *) is 4 bytes." - that's irrelevant, `sizeof(int)` is what matters.

Comment: What I meant to say was how many jumps will the pointer take i.e. how many ints will it have to jump over. But, post your comment, I can see how it can be misleading. Thanks for the correction. I like your precise definition.